# Is it possible to apply a filter to a specific sheet based on a parameter?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have 6+ sheets on my dashboard and I want to be able to filter/search a value, but only apply it to the sheet I selected.

**Further explanation:**

I have a parameter list w/ the following values: Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3

Based on this parameter, I have a calculated field that outputs the values from Sheet1 if Sheet1 was selected, and so on.

**If parameter is Sheet1, then I want to filter/search only in Sheet1. If it's Sheet2, I want to filter/search on Sheet2 only.**

Is this possible on Tableau Desktop?

I'm not able to provide a workbook, apologies in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello datascientistwannabe,
Don't worry about the workbook, its not needed and besides, if you were to share something, always best to use Superstore.

Yes, the great thing about Tableau is that you can be really specific about how interactions affect different vizzes. You have the choice of defining filtering from the actions menu by decided which sheets shall be targeted, and for greater granularity, you can even determine which fields are affected rather than all fields.

Also, you could tie calculations to parameters so as a parameter is updated, so too is the calculation, and then you can simply use the calculation.

Or, if you really want control, how about using different data sets for your visuals, controlling them by parameter, and then using *Set Parameter* actions, to populate parameters using data from a different source.

Steve